# Continue outside of loop error

Tags: java

I am working on a project in Java and I have written an if statement in order to call different constructors depending on what the user inputs (whether they want to load the default file or choose their own file path). However it seems  to only be going to the else statement not the if statement. I tried to put continue after calling the constructor but I get an error.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ShortenerUtility {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Would you like to open the default file?");
        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input1;
        input1 = sc1.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        System.out.println(input1);

        if (input1 == "yes")
        {
            Shortener s1 = new Shortener();

        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Please Enter the file path");
            Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
            String input2;
            input2 = sc1.nextLine();
            Shortener s2 = new Shortener(input2);
        }

    }
}
```

This returns the following:

```
Would you like to open the default file?
Yes
yes
Please Enter the file path
```

When I put the continue after the Shortener I get this:

```
Shortener s1 = new Shortener();
continue;
```

With this error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    continue cannot be used outside of a loop

    at ShortenerUtility.main(ShortenerUtility.java:20)
```

Comment: Use _equals_ to compare strings, not _==_ .

Comment: in addition continue can´t be applied outside of loops, which the conditional `if` doesn´t belong to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When comparing Strings you need to use `.equals()` instead of `==`, like so:

```
if (input1.equals("yes")) { ... }
```

Comment: Ah okay thank you, I'm new to Java and I have not come across that as of yet. Thank you for your help!